# TSQL Cursor Infinite Loop without TOP xxx in SELECT Statement

Tags: t-sql, cursor

I have a curious problem with an infinite loop in a TSQL cursor. The cursor loops infinitely when I do not add TOP 300 to the defining select statement of the cursor. The following is an example of the code: Any assistance to this issue is much appreciated.

```
DECLARE @Done BIT
SET @Done = 0

DECLARE cursOut CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR
SELECT
    --TOP 300
    FirstName FirstName
    ,LastName LastName
    ,MiddleName MiddleName
    ,Email Email
    ,Address1 Address1
    ,Address2 Address2
    ,City City
    ,[State] [State]
       FROM StagedUsers

OPEN cursOut;

WHILE (@Done = 0)
   BEGIN       
 --Fetch next row
    FETCH NEXT
    FROM cursOut
    INTO ,@v_FirstName
        ,@v_LastName
        ,@v_MiddleName
        ,@v_Email
        ,@v_Address1
        ,@v_Address2
        ,@v_City
        ,@v_State

    IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @Done = 1
        BREAK
    END

    --if @batch = 0
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --process statements
    --updates or insert statements


    --Commit transaction    
    COMMIT TRANSACTION

--End While             
    END 


--CleanUp:
CLOSE cursOut
DEALLOCATE cursOut
```

Thanks,
Renegrin

Comment: Are you inserting in the same table from which you are selecting?

Comment: No I am not updating or inserting to the same table.

Comment: your cursor definition seems to be missing a `FROM` clause. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: Ah, cut and paste error. Its fixed now.

Comment: Are you certain it is looping infinitely or are there just a lot of records? I'm fairly certain this will only process 300 records then stop.

Comment: Yes very certain. When I add the TOP 300 it processes very quickly and completes. Without in just goes on indefinitely.

Comment: Of course if you have a lot of records you would not under any circumstances want to use a cusor. WHy are you doing such a thing? There are set-based solutions for most things a cursor can do and they will run much faster. What are you trying to do? I doubt you are ina an infinite loop, a cursor can easily take a day or more to process a lot of records.

Comment: How many rows are there in the `StagedUsers` table? Have you watched execution plan? How much time does it take to process one record?

Comment: Currently there are only 300 records it takes 2min. If I have 100K it takes 18 mins if I supply the TOP statement. If I don't it loops forever. I can't watch the execution plan directly because its in an SSIS package and remote. I'd never implement this process this way I'd make it set based, but I inherited this implementation.

Comment: What happens between `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT TRANSACTION`?

Comment: I either update or insert into production tables.

Comment: 2 minutes for 300 records? It is not an infinite loop, it just takes a very long time. If you left it for a few days you would either see it finish or you would run out of temp space. I see no evidence of an infinite loop, just a very inefficient process.

Comment: I think it is not commiting somewhere. Try add the line `IF @@ERROR <> 0 ROLLBACK` right after the `COMMIT TRANSACTION`

Answer (score 0):

First I think you do not need transaction here, I presume it is only one statement executed, so remove transaction from code.

Second do it without @done flag, it is confusing (it is probably not problem here).

```
DECLARE @v_FirstName VARCHAR(500),@v_LastName VARCHAR(500),@v_MiddleName VARCHAR(500),@v_Email VARCHAR(500),@v_Address1 VARCHAR(500),@v_Address2 VARCHAR(500),@v_City VARCHAR(500),@v_State VARCHAR(500)

DECLARE cursOut CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT FirstName FirstName,LastName LastName,MiddleName MiddleName,Email Email,Address1 Address1,Address2 Address2,City City,[State] [State]
FROM StagedUsers

OPEN cursOut;

FETCH NEXT FROM cursOut INTO @v_FirstName,@v_LastName,@v_MiddleName,@v_Email,@v_Address1,@v_Address2,@v_City,@v_State

declare @i int = 1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN       
print cast(@i as varchar(10))

--> statement here

FETCH NEXT FROM cursOut INTO @v_FirstName,@v_LastName,@v_MiddleName,@v_Email,@v_Address1,@v_Address2,@v_City,@v_State

set @i = @i + 1     
END 

CLOSE cursOut
DEALLOCATE cursOut
```

Do you want to update current row where cursor point? If so, there is way to do it.

Is there any indexes on table? Can you post an update query?